# Submit values of the selected row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to submit values of the selected row to the different page :

here is the html

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr style = 'background-color: white'>
                <th> <i class="fa fa-male"></i> Name </th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Particular</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Unit</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Quantity</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>From</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Date</th>
                <th><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>TAKE actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

              <tr>
                <td>sssssss</td>
                <td>sneh pandy</td>
                <td>dkfgh</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>Snehp</td>
                <td>2014-03-21 10:01:52 UTC
                <td><form action="/requisitions/3" class="button_to" method="post"><div><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" /><input class="btn btn-danger" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete?" type="submit" value="Remove" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="f6KDE+0KcG+ACeCq/7jIzWc++eu4/1XuIfMf6JM+Bgc=" /></div></form>
                    <form action="/po" class="button_to" method="get"><div><input class="po" data-confirm="Really wants to generate Po?" type="submit" value="PO" /></div></form>
                    <form action="/capax" class="button_to" method="get"><div><input class="btn btn-warning" data-confirm="Are you sure?" type="submit" value="Capax" /></div></form>
                </td>
             <tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <div>
            <table >
                <tr>
                    <td>

                     </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**jquery**

```
$(function(){

        $('.po').click(function(){


                var $row = $(this).parents('tr'); 
                var name1 =  $row.find('td:eq(0)').html();
                alert($row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
                alert($row.find('td:eq(2)').html());
                alert($row.find('td:eq(3)').html());
                alert($row.find('td:eq(4)').html());
                 alert(name1);

        });
    });
```

**till now i can get the values of the specific rows but how can i submit to the next page**

**EG:**
 `after submitting`

I have a `text_field` on another page and
   the default value should be **name1** (from jq).

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sneh_pandya/M8Q8a/#&togetherjs=kKcJvkmJfb)

Comment: are you using any server-side scripting?

Comment: Why not use setAttribute() ?

Comment: Then you should tag ruby with your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect to the second page and pass the values as query string parameters:

```
$('.po').click(function() {
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr'); 
    var name1 =  $row.find('td:eq(0)').html();
    var name2 =  $row.find('td:eq(1)').html();
    var url = '/second_page?' + 
        'name1=' + encodeURIComponent(name1) + 
        '&name2=' + encodeURIComponent(name2);

    window.localtion.href = url;
});
```

Comment: not working..i have the `text-box` having class `box` in `/po` page i want to put value of `name1` in that text_box

Comment: It's the server side script that you are redirecting to that should read the query string parameters and assign them to the proper textbox.

Answer (score -1):

For there several approaches possible. Either of the below solution may help you.

1. Please use request/session object on the source JSP to set the values of element as attribute and access on the target page by attribute name.
2. Use model driven approach to send a list of object to the controller.

Steps:

1. Create a model with attributes same name and data type as used in your jsp.
2. Iterate over a list of the model created above.
3. Set the values to the attribute inside the loop.
4. Follow the steps inside a form on the jsp. Now once you submit the form the list of model object will be submitted to the controller.